# Лишние символы

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Вопрос такой, почему при выводе команды:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('C:/private/filetest_01.txt'); ?>
```

на страничке появляются лишние символы помимо содержимого filetest_01.txt? С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: какие именно лишние символы появляются?

Comment: кодировка.

Comment: Появляется п»їThis is being read вместо This is being read

Answer (score 3):

Связано с тем, что либо файл со скриптом (откуда вы делаете `file_get_contents`), либо файл `filetest_01.txt` сохранен в UTF-8 **с BOM**.

Пересохраните их **без BOM**.

Comment: спасибо, попробую)